# Running a Laravel Artisan command as a new process

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

So in general you can say `exec('MyCommand &> /dev/null &')` in php and `MyCommand` will be executed as a seperate process, so your primary php execution can continue on it's merry way.

Oddly, if you try to do this using Laravel's `Artisan`, something goes sideways. For instance, `exec('php artisan command &> /dev/null &')` results, surprisingly, in the process still just hanging until the artisan command finishes. If you wrap the artisan command in a bash script, it won't execute at all.

Why is this, and how can I execute an artisan command in a new, detached process?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create a new process to run it:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();

switch($pid)
{
    case -1:    // pcntl_fork() failed
        die('could not fork');

    case 0:    // you're in the new (child) process
        exec("php artisan command");

        // controll goes further down ONLY if exec() fails
        echo 'exec() failed';

    default:  // you're in the main (parent) process in which the script is running
        echo "hello";
}
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't think I can use `pcntl_fork()` from an Apache module call, as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826530/pcntl-fork-returning-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-pcntl-fork) question.

Comment: Are you sure it's not just because the pcntl_* functions are disabled in your php.ini file?

Comment: They were disabled, and I enabled them out of curiosity- however, I then found the first comment on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14737821/771665) answer, which pretty explicitly states those function are disabled in the Apache config because they don't work.